# Button not changing the Label on Clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        info.Visible = false;
        meeting.Visible = true;
        member.Visible = true;
        label.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime Now = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime wed1 = getFirstWednesdayOfMonth(Now);
        DateTime wed3 = getThirdWednesdayOfMonth(Now);

        if (Now < wed1)
        {
            Label5.Text = "The next meeting is on" + "\n" + wed1.ToShortDateString() + "\nat 7 pm in room S242";
        }
        else if (Now < wed3)
        {
            Label5.Text = "The next meeting is on" + "\n" + wed3.ToShortDateString() + "\nat 7 pm in room S242";
        }
    }

    protected DateTime getFirstWednesdayOfMonth(DateTime seedDate)
    {
        DateTime wed1 = new DateTime(seedDate.Year, seedDate.Month, 1);
        while (wed1.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            wed1 = wed1.AddDays(1);
        }
        return wed1;
    }
    protected DateTime getThirdWednesdayOfMonth(DateTime seedDate)
    {
        DateTime wed3 = new DateTime(seedDate.Year, seedDate.Month, 15);
        while (wed3.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            wed3 = wed3.AddDays(1);
        }
        return wed3;
    }

    protected void btnInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnInfo.Visible = false;
        info.Visible = true;

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (validateFirst.IsValid && validateLast.IsValid && validatePhone.IsValid && validateEmail.IsValid)
            {
                lblThanks.Text = "Thanks! you will contacted in 2 business days!";
                info.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedValue == "analyst")
        {


        }
    }
}
```

**and Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .heading
        {
            text-align: center;
            border-style: double;
            background-color:#F2A988;
            font-family:Sans-Serif;
            font-weight:bold;

        }
        #wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 400px; 
            text-align:left;
        }
        .style1
        {
            text-align: center;
            font-family:Sans-Serif;
        }
        .style2
        {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 642px; width: 911px; " id="wrapper">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="heading">
        ABC Computer Club - Inquiry Form</div>
        <br />

    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Calendar>



        <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblThanks" runat="server" 
        style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
    <br />



        <br />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnInfo" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" 
         style="font-weight: 700" 
        Text="I'd like to receive more information!" Width="261px" 
        onclick="btnInfo_Click" />

    <div runat="server" id="info" 
        style="position:relative; top: -1px; left: 7px; width: 463px; height: 415px;">
        <span class="style2">If you would like to join the club or receive more 
        information about the club, fill in the form below and click the submit button.</span><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
            style="font-weight: 700; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
            Text="First Name:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
            style="font-weight: 700; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
            Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" 
            style="font-weight: 700; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
            Text="Phone #:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" 
            style="font-weight: 700; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
            Text="Email:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Submit" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validateFirst" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtFName" ErrorMessage="First Name is Required" 
            style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validateLast" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtLName" ErrorMessage="Last Name is Required" 
            style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validatePhone" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ErrorMessage="Phone Number is invalid" 
            style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
            ValidationExpression="^[01]?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validateEmail" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" 
            style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" 
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </div>

    <div runat="server" id="meeting" 
        style="position:absolute; top: 150px; left: 580px; width: 232px; height: 64px; text-align: center; margin-top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-weight:bold;">
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Test"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        </div>



    <div runat="server" id="label" style="width: 308px; position:absolute; top: 45px; left: 550px; margin-top: 0px;" 
        class="style1">
        Click Below to find out when
        <br />
        the club meets next</div>

    <div runat="server" id="member" 



        style="position:absolute; top: 28px; left:880px; width: 274px; height: 441px; font-family:Sans-Serif;">
        <b>View Members by Program:<br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="175px" Width="213px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="all">All</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="programmer">Computer Programmer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="itss">Information Technologies Support Services</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="analyst">Systems Analyst</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        </b></div>

    <div style="position:absolute; top: 99px; left: 600px; width: 192px; text-align: center; margin-top: 0px;">
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" 
            Text="Next Meeting" />
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is whenever I click **"Next Meeting"** nothing happens whereas *it should set the label text to Next Available first or third wednesday of the month*. It did worked before but since when I copied the whole code to a new website it is not working. What may be the problem?

Comment: Please revise your title to something more descriptive of the actual issue.

Comment: Also, did you check your new website to see that it is configured correctly to use the correct .NET version?

Comment: Define "not working". Not posting back, not changing the label after post back, what?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this code? Is your button3_click called? Is one of your if true? Try to remove the newline character

Comment: Tested your code and today (2012/07/21) none of your if's is true, so your label5 don't get any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third case

```
DateTime getFirstWednesdayOfNextMonth(DateTime seedDate) 
{ 
    int year = seedDate.Year;
    int month = seedDate.Month+1;
    if (month > 12) 
    {
        month = 1; 
        year = year + 1;
    }
    DateTime wed1 = new DateTime(year, month, 1); 
    while (wed1.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday) 
    { 
       wed1 = wed1.AddDays(1); 
    } 
    return wed1; 
}
```

and add an ending else to your Button3_Click

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    DateTime Now = DateTime.Today;    
    DateTime wed1 = getFirstWednesdayOfMonth(Now);    
    DateTime wed3 = getThirdWednesdayOfMonth(Now);    
    DateTime wedNext = getFirstWednesdayOfNextMonth(Now);    

    if (Now < wed1)    
    {    
        Label5.Text = "The next meeting is on" + "\n" + wed1.ToShortDateString() + "\nat 7 pm in room S242";    
    }    
    else if (Now < wed3)    
    {    
        Label5.Text = "The next meeting is on" + "\n" + wed3.ToShortDateString() + "\nat 7 pm in room S242";    
    }    
    else     
    {    
        Label5.Text = "The next meeting is on" + "\n" + wedNextMonth.ToShortDateString() + "\nat 7 pm in room S242";    
    }    
}
```

By the way, when you know the first wednesday of the month, calculating the other two is simple a matter of adding 14 to the first one.

```
  DateTime wed1 = getFirstWednesdayOfMonth(Now); 
  DateTime wed3 = wed.AddDays(14);
  DateTime wedNext = wed3.AddDays(14);
  // But it could be in the same month (1,8,15,22,29)
  if(wedNext.Month == wed3.Month)
     wedNext = wedNext.AddDays(7);
```

Answer (score 2):

That code has never worked correctly. Maybe it has worked seemingly before 18. Jul 2012 which was  the third wednesday in this month, because then `(Now < wed3) == true`.

Now neither `Now < wed1` nor `Now < wed3` can be true which is the only way to change the label's text property.

```
if (Now < wed1)
{
    Label5.Text = "The next meeting is on" + "\n" + wed1.ToShortDateString() + "\nat 7 pm in room S242";
}
else if (Now < wed3)
{
    Label5.Text = "The next meeting is on" + "\n" + wed3.ToShortDateString() + "\nat 7 pm in room S242";
}
```

Maybe you need to tell us your real requirement. What should your program do?

You might also want to put the default settings in page_load in a `if(!IsPostback)` check, otherwise the `Calendar.SelectedDate` always is overwritten.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // not on postbacks, f.e. when the user selected a date
    Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
    // ....
}
```

---

> But one thing, if there's no First or Third Wednesday is available, it
>   should show the first wednesday of next month. Right?

That's the missing requirement i've asked for. Since the third wednesday is already in the past, you want to return the third wednesday of the nex month:

```
public static DateTime getNextWeekDay(DateTime date, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, int weekNum)
{
    if (weekNum < 1 || weekNum > 4)
        throw new ArgumentException("Number of week must be between 1 and 4.", "weekNum");

    int inWeekNum = date.Date.Day / 7;
    if (inWeekNum >= weekNum)
    {
        var nextMonth = date.AddMonths(1);
        date = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month, 1);
    }
    DateTime currentDate = date;
    int currentWeekNum = 0;
    while (currentWeekNum < weekNum)
    {
        if (currentDate.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
            currentWeekNum++;
        if (currentWeekNum == weekNum)
            break;
        else
            currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    return currentDate;
}
```

Yiou can use it this way:

```
DateTime wed1 = getNextWeekDay(Now, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, 1);
DateTime wed3 = getNextWeekDay(Now, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, 3);
```

Comment: My real requirement is I want to show the next Available 1st or 3rd wednesday of the month. Which I did by setting the label.

Comment: @AnkurKaushal: There is no  "next available third of this month" since it is already in the past. So does the program work correctly?

Comment: Everything works correctly except the "Next Meeting" button. :/

Comment: But one thing, if there's no First or Third Wednesday is available, it should show the first wednesday of next month. Right?

Comment: @AnkurKaushal: That's the only thing i've asked. So that's the bug in your code. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have to use (==True) in the "if-else" context?

Comment: @AnkurKaushal: Edited my answer to provide a `getNextWeekDay` method which returns the next month's n-th week if necessary.